# How can I predict which Facebook friends chat with each other based off online status and Facebook's "last time active" feature

Tags: facebook, api, statistics, bigdata

If you look at Facebook's chat (https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uhoT.png) you can see it says the last time the specified user was active.

So if two friends both were last active 2 minutes ago and then they both go online and become inactive again, there is a high likelihood that they were chatting.

I want to know if anyone has any idea what the best way to go about accessing this data would be. I don't think it's available through the Facebook API but am unsure.

Furthermore, I would like to perform some sort of probabilistic statistical analysis on the data to see how confident the algorithm is with its guess of whether or not two friends were chatting.

I know this question is very broad so ideas on either acquiring the data or design and analysis of the data would much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is not available via the Graph API, so I don't see a chance here to really implement what you are planning.